# Is there a way to plot points and a line on the same plot?

Tags: r, plot

I have a vector called `GoldbachCounts` which I want to graph against a predictor function. I want to graph the predictor function as a line, overtop of the points of the vector. The code I used threw a few different errors depending on what I was trying, but the latest was `Error in plot.window(...) : invalid 'ylim' value`, even though I specified a ylim which I knew would work for both. This code also displays the legend I wanted, even though it threw an error, but it did not display the plot itself. The code that threw this error follows

```
x <- seq.int(1,300000,1)
y <- x/((log(x))^2)
plot(x, GoldbachCounts, main = "Goldbach Counts", xlab = "x", ylab = "y", ylim = 13000,
     type = "b", pch = 20, cex = .25,
     lines(x, y, col = "red", cex = 1.5), 
     legend("topleft", c("Counts", "Predictor"), fill = c("black", "red")))
```

By changing `ylim` to `c(0,13000)`, it now throws the error `Error in strsplit(log, NULL) : non-character argument`

Comment: you're passing `lines()` and `legend()` inside `plot()`, move them outside as separate calls

Comment: What is your vector `GoldbachCounts` like? Can you post it?

Comment: ```lines()``` and ```legend()``` inside ```plot()``` was the problem. The thing I found online had said that was how you do it. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

`ylim` takes both a minimum and a maximum for the axis. So try changing to `ylim = c(1, 13000)`, or whatever you wish the minimum to be

Comment: Thanks! This changed the error to ```Error in strsplit(log, NULL) : non-character argument```